# XAML UWP AppBar not responding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, appbar

I got a strange behavior in my UWP App.

I have an AppBar with three buttons on top of my page. When I'm navigating to my page via the NavView the AppBar is not responding, neither the buttons nor the menu (the three dots), there is also no "mouseover". When I'm navigating to the page again it works fine.

As far as I could see is that when I remove the "isOpen" property in the code it seems to be working. As soon as I set the property (either in C# or in the XAML code) it is unresponsive at the first navigation

```
<AppBar x:Name="AppBar" IsSticky="True" Margin="0,0,0,0"  IsOpen="True" >
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <AppBarButton Label="Reset" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonResetGrid" />
    <AppBarButton Label="Export" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonExport" />
    <AppBarButton Label="Refresh" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonRefreshCode" />
  </StackPanel>
</AppBar>
```

This is when navigating to the page for the first time

Not Working:
[image]

after navigating a second time (you can see the mouseover):

Expected Behavior
[image]

Maybe someone has an idea or a good hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar#remarks) in official document, You should use the AppBar only when you are upgrading a Universal Windows 8 app that uses the AppBar, and need to minimize changes. For new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) control instead. Please try use `CommandBar` like the follow.

```
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarButton Label="Reset" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonResetGrid" />
    <AppBarButton Label="Export" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonExport" />
    <AppBarButton Label="Refresh" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonRefreshCode" />
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Like" Label="Like" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike" Label="Dislike" />
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

    <CommandBar.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Now playing..." Margin="12,14"/>
    </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```

**Update**

If you want to make all AppBarButtons conllection left, you need to custom CommandBar style like the the [link](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/NavigationViewTest/blob/master/NavigationViewTest/SamplePage1.xaml#L11) .

Comment: This seems to be working. Is there any way to align the buttons to the left as they are on the right per default?

Comment: @MichalskiM, If you want to make all AppBarButtons left, you need to custom  [CommandBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx) style.

Comment: @MichalskiM, I have updated the case reply and provide the complete CommandBar style that AppBarButton collection left,

Comment: It looks better with the CommandBar but I have the same behavior as soon as I set the isOpen Property to true when the page is loaded. But as soon as I leave the focus to another App it starts working. You got any idea left?

Comment: @MichalskiM, Sorry,  it is hard to approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I achived it by setting the IsOpen property with the Loaded event and it works. I don't know why this does not work when setting it in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

*Can you please try as that it will probably work:*

```
 <Page.TopAppBar>
        <AppBar x:Name="AppBar" IsSticky="True" Margin="0,0,0,0"  IsOpen="True">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="Reset" Width="140" Height="80" Click="ButtonResetGrid_Click"/>
                    <Button Content="Export" Width="140" Height="80" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonExport_Click"/>
                    <Button Content="Refresh" Width="140" Height="80" Icon="AllApps" Click="ButtonRefreshCode_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>

        </AppBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply but unfortunately this did not work. It's the exact same behavior.